# Gradient Descent with Linear regression in Sklearn

Tags: scikit-learn, linear-regression, gradient-descent

The Linear regression model from `sklearn` uses a closed or normal equation to find the parameters. However with large datasets Gradient Descent is said to be more efficient. Is there any way to use the `LinearRegression` from sklearn using gradient descent.

Answer (score 1):

The function you are looking for is: `sklearn.linear_model.SGDRegressor`

You can modify the `loss` hyperparameter which will define the loss function to be used.

Be aware that the SGD of `SGDRegressor` stands for Stochastic Gradient Descent. Which means that the gradient of the loss is estimated **each sample** at a time and the model is updated along the way with a decreasing strength schedule (aka learning rate).

Comment: I totally get you. I just had a query whether I could use ```batch gradient descent``` or ```mini-batch gradient descent``` instead of SGD